# strange svn problem in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have installed Subclipse inside my Eclipse. I can successfully connect to http://svn.python.org/projects/peps/trunk, but when I tried to connect to [svn://svn/appwork.org/utils](http://svn://svn/appwork.org/utils), I got an error saying:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it.   svn: Can't connect to host 'svn': No connection could be
>   made because the target machine actively refused it.

Does anyone knows the answer to this question? Thanks a lot!

**Edit**
I actually overlooked the error in the svn address. Even if I tried with "svn://svn.appwork.org/utils", I still got another error:

```
A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host.  
svn: Can't connect to host 'svn.appwork.org': A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `svn://svn.appwork.org/utils` instead of `svn://svn/appwork.org/utils`. With a dot, not slash.

Comment: sorry that I overlooked the error in the address. Please see my update in the post. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: ok, check with `telnet svn.appwork.org 3690`. If that cannot connect too, the problem is in your firewall or network.

Comment: I got "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out". Does this mean I cannot access `svn://svn.*****` but I can access `http://svn.*****`?

Comment: yes, probably your firewall blocks outgoing connections to the SVN port